# Encode Audio using Sink Writer

Tags: c++, audio, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx) article that explaing how to encode a video using Media Foundation.

I am trying to encode an audio using the principle used in the above link.

I am stuck on setting a correct input media type for the sink writer.

Here is that part:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_Float);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, cChannels);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, sampleRate);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);
```

My code fails on the last line while setting the input media type.

Any help, how to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create the SinkWriter? Did you try with MFAudioFormat_PCM?

Comment: MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"output.m4a", NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

Yes, I have tried both PCM and Float. They can't be set

Comment: I think you also need to supply MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE  in the media type. It must be set to 16. Check the Input types requirements here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785(v=vs.85).aspx
The sample rate must be either 44100 or 48000. The subtype must be MFAudioFormat_PCM.

Comment: MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL may not be able to guess that you need to encode to an mp4 container from the m4a extension. You might need to supply MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4 containe type using the MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE attribute when calling MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL. Another option would be to use MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink and MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink instead.

Comment: And the most important thing is that you need to call AddStream on the Sink Writer, prior to calling SetMediaType, with an output audio type enumerated by a call to MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes function with MFAudioFormat_AAC subtype if you need to encode audio as AAC.

Comment: @VuVirt thanks for your comments. I fixed that issue. I guess now I'm on a right way. Again, Thank you very much..!!!

Comment: please accept my final answer. Thanks!

Comment: sure. give me time to try and finalize everything.

Comment: One more question @VuVirt. Suppose I have an audio with 2 channels. I want to create an IMFSample which holds 1 frame (2 samples` 1 per channel). If I have total of X samples (X/2 per each sample). How much is going to be the sample duration?
I am setting it
pSample->SetSampleDuration(10^7 / sample_rate). Is this wrong?

Comment: Check the link again. It says: After the input type is set, the encoder derives the following values and adds them to the media type:
• MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND 
• MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT 
• MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE 
You can calculate the sample duration from these values. You are not restricted to keep only 2 samples in a IMFSample. You can have more audio samples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127447/discussion-between-mbaros-and-vuvirt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to supply MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE in the media type. It must be set to 16. Check the Input types requirements here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785(v=vs.85).aspx. The sample rate must be either 44100 or 48000. The subtype must be MFAudioFormat_PCM.

The most important thing is that you need to call AddStream on the Sink Writer, prior to calling SetMediaType, with an output audio type enumerated by a call to MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes function with MFAudioFormat_AAC subtype if you need to encode audio as AAC.

MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL may not be able to guess that you need to encode to an mp4 container from the m4a extension. You might need to supply MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4 containe type using the MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE attribute when calling MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL. Another option would be to use MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink and MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink instead.

Comment: Just one comment. MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL is able to guess the correct container out from the output name.